# where can I fined a list of salesforce certificated developers

Tags: certification, developer

where can I fined a list of salesforce certificated developers (preferred in US and EU)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search the [AppExchange Developers](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/developers) area for a list of those that have voluntarily posted their information, and you can [verify their certification](http://certification.salesforce.com/verification). You can also search [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/vsearch/f?keywords=salesforce.com+certified) for individuals that are certified. Salesforce does have an internal database of certified individuals, but they do not hand out this information wholesale, as a matter of privacy. You'll have to find people that are willing to be found.